# How can I hide sensitive data before commiting to GitHub (or any other Git repo)?

Tags: python, git, github

I'm creating a code to demonstrate how to consume a REST service in Python, but I don't want my API keys to be visible to people when I push my changes to GitHub. How can I hide such information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re using Python, you might consider using the [`keyring` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring). This allows you to store secret information in the system keychain, and then there’s no risk that it could be accidentally checked into Git.

Here’s a simple example for storing and retrieving an API key, based on the docs:

```
>>> import keyring
>>> keyring.set_password("my_api_key", "username", "ABC1234SEKRIT")
>>> keyring.get_password("my_api_key", "username")
'ABC1234SEKRIT'
```

Comment: @alexwlchan Does this require only python installed in OS or a python project? Can it be used with other languages? Where do I enter the commands?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the cleanest solution would be using environment variables, so you can use different values for your variables on the development machine and on the server. You can find a good explanation about that here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Answer (score 1):

Considering storing this kind of data in a config file that isn't tracked by git.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`git-crypt`**](https://www.agwa.name/projects/git-crypt/)  for that.

It enables transparent encryption and decryption of files in a git repository. **Files which you choose to protect are encrypted when committed, and decrypted when checked out.**

It lets you freely share a repository containing a mix of public and private content. git-crypt gracefully degrades, so developers without the secret key can still clone and commit to a repository with encrypted files. This lets you store your secret material (such as keys or passwords) in the same repository as your code, without requiring you to lock down your entire repository.

Check out this [blog](http://www.twinbit.it/en/blog/storing-sensitive-data-git-repository-using-git-crypt).